# Highcharts - Dual yAxis not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I have this chart

http://jsfiddle.net/WMa55/3/

```
        series: [

            {
                name: 'distance',
                type: 'column',
                data: [4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 1.0, 0.0, 9.0],
                borderRadius: 2
            }, {
                name: 'weight',
                color: '#89A54E',
                type: 'spline',
                data: [165.0, 160.9, 159.5, 155.5, 162.2, 179.5, 125.2],
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: '--'
                }
            }
        ]
```

I would like to display two yAxis labels, one on right side and one on left side.  It seems to just be using one.

I think this is due to the custom label formatting, but not positive. I don't want the two sets of data to use the same range. Anyone have an idea on why it would only be showing the one axis?

Comment: Still investigating but you also need to set the yAxis to use for the "weight" series to yAxis: 1 (0-based index of yAxis avaialble).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got two problems I can see right off the top:

1.) You haven't assigned any series to plot against the 2nd y axis.

```
yAxis: 1
```

2.) You have a right margin of -4, which is suppressing the drawing of the right y axis.

```
marginRight: -4,  // where's the axis going to draw if it doesn't have space?
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WMa55/4/).

Comment: thanks, i have been messing with this for to long.  Appreciate your assistance.